# How to find minimum digit in a number using recursion [Python]

Tags: python, recursion

I have a function that gets a number and should return the minimum digit.
This is what I was trying to do, but maybe I didn't fully understand how recursion works.

```
def min_dig(num):
    minimum = 9
    if num < 10:
        return num
    min_dig(num / 10)
    if num % 10 < minimum:
        minimum = num % 10
    return minimum


print(min_dig(98918))
```

Output is 8 but supposed to be 1.

Comment: Kryrena and LEGION GREEN 's answers are what you wanted to do. Since they're identical, please accept the oldest one.

Comment: Actually, they are not *exactly* identical.  But agreed with @Swifty.  You could accept either one and mark the *check* mark as accepted answer.

Comment: The "else" is negligible :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what the recursion trying to do is like this:

```
def min_dig(num):
    if num < 10:
        return num
    return min(num % 10, min_dig(num // 10))

print(min_dig(98918))
```

If the number is smaller than 10, then its minimum digit is itself. If the number is larger than 10, we just compare its last digit and the minimum digit of the number composed of all its digits except the last digit, and return the smaller one.

Answer (score 3):

I have modified your function in a way that works and I think is simpler to understand.

```
def min_dig(number):
    if number < 10:
        return number
    else:
        return min(number % 10, min_dig(number // 10))
```

This also uses recursion, I just do it as the return. Here you basically compare `(number % 10)` and `(min_dig(number // 10)` and  just return the lowest. This way you can compare all the digits in your number between them. Hope this helps.

Comment: ```else``` is redundant here.  See prev. post.

Comment: @DanielHao yes you are right, I think the previous post had been posted while I was writing my solution. Just muscle memory in typing the `else`

Answer (score 0):

Lets start by thinking about this in the logic for now;

You get given a number,
You split the number into an array of numbers,
You loop through that array and store the first digit in a variable,
For all of the next iterations of the array, you compare that index in the array with what's stored in the variable, and if it's smaller, you overwrite the variable with the new number, if not, continue,
Return the number in the variable

Here's some Pseudocode that should help you out a little, you can convert it into python yourself

```
number = 98918
numberArray = number.split
smallest = numberArray[0]
for (digit in numberArray){
    if (digit < smallest){
        smallest = digit
    }
}
print(smallest)
```

Comment: This works, but doesn't use recursion. Please read the question carefully.

Answer (score -1):

You have made minimum as your local variable so every time it will assign the value as 9. Try to make it global variable.

```
minimum = 9
def min_dig(num):
    global minimum
    if num < 10:
        return num
    min_dig(num // 10)
    if num % 10 < minimum:
        minimum = num % 10
    return minimum


print(min_dig(98918))
```

Comment: While that may or may not work, using a global variable for this is **terrible** advice.